# CSS background color width reduces when browser window is resized

Tags: html, css

I have a page but when I resize the browser window the background color gets cut down. I want the color to expand to the full browser width. One of my divs is bigger than the other ones. What is the fix for this?

The CSS is below:

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* ==========================================================================
   RESET STYLES
   ========================================================================== */
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #222;
}

body {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

img {
    border: 0 none;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   BASE STYLES
   ========================================================================== */

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Sans-serif;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    color: #595959;
}

.col-full {
    width: 1014px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}   

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}
/* ==========================================================================
   HEADER STYLES
   ========================================================================== */   
#header h1 {
    margin-top: 26px;
    float: left;
}

h1 a span {
    display: none;
}

#login-form {
    float: right;
    margin: 25px 92px 12px 0;
}
    #login-form input {
        width: 150px;
        height: 29px;
        line-height: 29px;
        border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
        color: #797979;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-left: 8px;
        margin-left: 3px;
    }
    #login-form #login-button {
        width: 72px;
        height: 30px;
        background: url(../img/login-bg.png) top repeat-x;
        border: 1px solid #494949;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding-left: 0;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #3f3f3f;
        filter: dropshadow(color=#3f3f3f, offx=1, offy=1);
    }

.form-buttons { 
    margin-left: 3px;
}
    .form-buttons a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #ef4926;
        margin-right: 116px;
    }

.nav {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 47px;
    background: #000;   
}
    .nav ul {
        margin-top: 10px;
        float: left;
    }
    .nav ul li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        margin-right: 53px;
    }
    .nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFF;
        /*font-size: 16px;*/
        font-size: 15px;
    }

.top-heading {
    background: #363737;
    height: 57px;
    border-top: 1px solid #727272;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #727272;
}
    .top-heading h2 {
        /*font-size: 28px;*/
        font-size: 27px;
        color: #FFF;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #282929;
        filter: dropshadow(color=#282929, offx=1, offy=1);
        padding-top:8px;
    }

#featured {
    background: url(../img/featured-gd.png) repeat-x;   
}
    #featured .col-full {
        background: url(../img/featured-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
    .featured-content {
        width: 454px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 40px;
    }
        .featured-content h2 {
            color: #FFF;
            /*font-size: 38px;*/
            font-size: 37px;
            line-height: 1.15;
            margin-top: 45px;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #282929;
            filter: dropshadow(color=#282929, offx=1, offy=1);
        }
        .featured-content p {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #FFF;
            line-height: 1.46;
        }
        .register-btn {
            display: block;
            width: 164px;
            height: 39px;
            text-decoration: none;
            background: url(../img/register-btn.png) repeat-x;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-top: 27px;
            font-size: 22px;
            color: #FFF;
            padding-top: 4px;
            -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 1px 1px #2e2e2e;
            box-shadow:  0px 0px 2px 2px #2e2e2e;
        }
        #featured img {
            margin-top: 6px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }


/* ==========================================================================
   MAIN STYLES
   ========================================================================== */   
#features {
    background: #ff5423;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#features h3 {
    line-height: 1.15;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    padding-top: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    /*font-size: 26px;*/
    font-size: 25px;
}

    .features-left {
        width: 447px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 62px;
    }

    .features-right {
        width: 472px;
        float: left;
    }

        .features-right ul {
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
        .features-right ul li {
            line-height: 1.76;
            color: #ffc3b2;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-left: 2px;
        }
        .features-right ul li span {
            font-size: 17px;
            color: #fefefe;
            position: relative;
            top: 2px;
        }
        .more-features {
            display: block;
            width: 144px;
            height: 28px;
            color: #fb3800;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            /*font-size: 17px;*/
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 4px;
            text-decoration: none;
            background: url(../img/more-features.png) repeat-x;
            margin-top: 38px;
            margin-bottom: 23px;
        }

#client-list {
    border-top: 4px solid #a6a6a6;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #c6c6c6;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}   
    #client-list .col-full {
        width: 1080px;
    }   
    #client-list h4 {
        color: #4d4d4d;
        /*font-size: 18px;*/
        font-size: 17px;
        margin-top: 39px;
    }
    #client-list .more-clients {
        float: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #ff5423;
    }
    #client-list img {
        margin-left: 90px;
        margin-top: -44px;
    }

#main {
    clear: both;
    background: url(../img/main-gd.png) repeat;
}
    .col-446 {
        width: 446px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 55px;
    }
    .col-476 {
        width: 476px;
        float: left;
    }
    .col-476 p {
        margin-right: 25px;
    }

    #main h3 {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        /*font-size: 28px;*/
        font-size: 27px;
        color: #535353;
        line-height: 1.07;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 14px;
    }
    #main p {
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.64;
        margin-bottom: 21px;
    }
    .site-features {
        margin-top: 32px;
        float: left;
    }
    .site-features li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 35px;
    }
        li.sf-last {margin-right: 0;}
    .site-features li a {

    }

    .join-box {

    }
    .join-btn {

    }
    .join-box p {

    }







/* ==========================================================================
   FOOTER STYLES
   ========================================================================== */   
h4 a span {
    display: none;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what browser and OS you're testing in?

Comment: on a windows OS, firefox, safari, internet explorer all have the same issue.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce the problem -I tried minimizing but I see no change. Can you provide additional information and preferably include snapshots?

Comment: Can you specify exact color getting reduces? Its working fine for me.

Comment: I added a screenshot in the question when the browser is minimized. See how the orange, the gray and the black color is not expanding to full browser width? That's the issue.

Comment: *I think you mean resized, not minimized

Comment: yes resized would be a more appropriate word :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way to solve this is to add a minimum width to your body. This way when the viewport is too narrow to show all your content, a horizontal scrollbar will allow the user to access the entire page. By the looks of your content, `min-width: 1100px;` would be just about right.

Comment: just to clarify - the min-width is based on the width of "client-logos.jpg" plus the block on the left. 1080px will also work. If this page is to be adapted for mobile viewingm, the whole layout needs reworking. There seem to be many issues with the assigned displays, position and width properties of most elements.

Comment: thanks, the page does not need to be adapted for mobile for now so this should be safe...

Comment: @ile can you give me a few examples for the 'issues withdisplays, position and width properties of most element', so that it could give me a starting point to reconsider my coding method. it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment re stylesheet issues. I had a hunch all wrapping containers ought to be inline-block, relative and 100% wide. After a thorough look at the markup, I understand the page is intended for screens ~1014px+ wide (nb not a bad thing). Personally, I try to make things as dynamic/size independent as possible. For instance, now `.col-446` and `.col-447` are set to 446px and 476px, I'd rather have them float left/right, width 45% of parent. Anyhow, your approach has consistency advantages and BigMackAttack's answer is good way to ensure proper display on smaller screens